# Chamar método ao fechar dialog

Tags: primefaces

Este código é o do showcase do `primefaces` :

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
    <p:commandButton value="Basic" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" />

    <p:commandButton value="Modal" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg2').show();" />

    <p:commandButton value="Effects" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg3').show();" /> 
</h:panelGrid>

<p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40">
    <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
</p:dialog>

<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100">
    <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
</p:dialog>   

<p:dialog header="Effects" widgetVar="dlg3" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="bounce" height="100">
    <h:outputText value="This dialog has nice effects." />
</p:dialog>
```

Coloquei pra ajudar no entendimento. Eu gostaria de saber como posso invocar um método caso eu feche o dialog pelo 'x' no canto superior direito como está na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na documentação do Primefaces Dialog ([primefaces_user_guide.pdf](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf)) tem um exemplo:

```
<p:dialog>
  <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{dialogBean.handleClose}" update="msg" />
  //Content
</p:dialog>

<p:messages id="msg" />
```

.

```
public class DialogBean {
  public void handleClose(CloseEvent event) {
    //Add facesmessage
  }
}
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.